# Laravel Password reset link is pointing to old APP_URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a Laravel 8 project which is using Laravel/UI for auth.

I changed the `APP_URL` in the `.env` file from the test domain extension to IP Address. But the password reset email is showing a link with the previous `APP_URL` as the base URL.

The following are steps that I have tried to solve this:

1. Change `APP_URL` in `.env` file
2. Change URL in `config/app.php` to the IP address instead of env variable.
3. Ran `php artisan config:clear`
4. Ran `php artisan cache:clear`
5. Ran `php artisan optimize:clear`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan queue:restart
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with url from where I was submitting the form. Laravel/UI reset password uses route() method to get the url for the password reset. Hence why the change in APP_URL and url variable didn't affect the link. A detailed explanation is available [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/password-reset-link-is-pointing-to-old-app-url)